# How to add a new tag into the content through java program in Arbortext editor 7.0

Tags: java, tags, editor

I was trying to automate a process of adding tag and removing it through a java program. For the same I was trying get Arbortext editor window control. And Did this code below :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/PTC/Arbortext Editor/bin/x86/editor.exe"+" "+"C:/JWBIntegration/JWBIntegeration/resource/testdata/Ia53cfdb05f8e11e49822a9299f05e77f.xml");  
LOG.info("Arbortext Loaded");  
Thread.sleep(30000);  
Window windowHandler = Application.getActiveWindow();  
LOG.info(windowHandler);  
windowHandler.close();
```

As per code the editor should be closed. But the program terminated with below error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.arbortext.epic.Application._GetActiveWindow()J
  at com.arbortext.epic.Application._GetActiveWindow(Native Method)
  at com.arbortext.epic.Application.access$700(Application.java:38)
  at com.arbortext.epic.Application$8.call(Application.java:500)
  at com.arbortext.epic.Application$8.call(Application.java:498)
  at com.arbortext.epic.AOMAccessController.execute(AOMAccessController.java:150)
  at com.arbortext.epic.Application.getActiveWindow(Application.java:511)
  at com.thomson.integration.content.AdditionalPartiesUpdateTest.testMetaData(AdditionalPartiesUpdateTest.java:42)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

[image:PTC Arbortext Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4tyh.png)

I am getting stuck here. Not able to get window handler and could not able go further for addition of AP tag. above image is screenshot of my Arbortext editor. In Lowermost row There is a tag named as AP followed by K and TC. I just need to put this tag into my content through java code. **How to do this ?**

Answer (score 0):

You should look into posting this question at https://www.ptcusercommunity.com/
If you want to automate Arbortext, you should also consult the manuals in the Arbortext Help Center. While there is general documentation on ACL throughout the manuals, you really want the Arbortext Command Language Reference. You can also get this documentation online through your PTC support account:
http://support.ptc.com/cs/help/arbortext_hc/ae70_hc/index.jspx?id=ID3907018505&action=show

Comment: Also raised same question there, but no response.